# no matching function for call to constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm writing a program that uses a simple eventqueue to simulate various processes in a bank. I have the following code implemented:

```
class CustomerEvent: public Event
{
    public:
        CustomerEvent(unsigned int t): Event(t)
        {}
};
```

This seems, to work, but when I try to call the constructor in another class,

```
class Customer
{
    private:
        CustomerEvent action;

    public:
        Customer(unsigned int t)
        {
            action = CustomerEvent(t);
        }

        CustomerEvent getAction()
        {
            return action;
        }

};
```

I get this

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘CustomerEvent::CustomerEvent()’
```

It seems like the compiler is interpreting the call of CustomerEvent's constructor incorrectly. Both classes are within the same file, so I don't think scope of the CustomerEvent class is an issue. I can post the code of the Event class if needed, but it's no more than an object that has an unsigned int. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly a dupe of something, but here goes: All members must be initialized before entering the main body of the constructor, so the compiler attempts to call `CustomerEvent`'s default constructor to perform initialization, which it cannot find because `CustomerEvent`'s default constructor does not exist. You need to take advantage of the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list): `Customer(unsigned int t): action(t) {}`

Comment: You never "call a constructor" yourself. I know it looks like you have, but you haven't. Please learn about initialisation and forget everything you learnt from Java-- C++ does not use reference semantics for object creation.